# Modo para traduzir website automaticamente

Tags: php, html, aplicação-web, htaccess, tradução

Tenho um site em português escrito em PHP e HTML. Gostaria de oferecer este site para outros países, mas sem ter que traduzir todo conteúdo manualmente. Por isso gostaria de uma ferramenta que traduzisse o site automaticamente quando a pessoa acessasse o link (http://site.com/english) ou (http://site.com/?lang=en), parecido com a opção de traduzir do Chrome. A única solução mais viável que encontrei foi o Google Website Translator:

```
https://translate.google.com/manager/website/
```

Assim o site fica com uma barrinha lateral onde a pessoa escolhe o idioma que quer ver a página. Porém, esse meio não faz a tradução automática da página, a pessoa tem que clicar para mudar para o idioma desejado.

Desculpe se minha pergunta é um pouco ampla. Alguém conhece alguma outra solução? Obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

Eu Particularmente [**gosto deste sistema*zito***](https://gist.github.com/mpezzi/348379), é simples e consegues fazer varias coisas com ele!

podes definir a linguagem por `$_GET`, ou seja é por url

Podes ter quantas linguagens necessitares, e é fácil de acrescentar traduções!

Aqui tens um exemplo:

```
//Definir linguagens a ser usadas:

define('LANG_ENGLISH', 'en');
define('LANG_FRENCH', 'fr');
define('LANG_SPANISH', 'es');

// Definir linguagem principal
$language = isset($_GET['l']) ? $_GET['l'] : LANG_ENGLISH;

// Mini-função que faz o seu trabalho:

function t($string, $args = array(), $langcode = NULL) {
  global $language, $translation;

  // Set language code.
  $langcode = isset($langcode) ? $langcode : $language;

  // Search for a translated string.
  if ( isset($translation[$langcode][$string]) ) {
    $string = $translation[$langcode][$string];
  }

  // Replace arguments if present.
  if ( empty($args) ) {
    return $string;
  } else {
    foreach ( $args as $key => $value ) {
      switch ( $key[0] ) {
        case '!':
        case '@':
        case '%':
        default: $args[$key] = $value; break;
      }
    }

    return strtr($string, $args);
  }
}
```

Para adicionares traduções:

**(noutro ficheiro a parte)**

```
//index.php
// incluir a mini-função acima se tiver noutro ficheiro
include('inc.language.php');
// adicionar traduções a uma certa linguagem exemplo:
$translation[LANG_SPANISH] = array(
  'Email' => 'email',
  'Name' => 'nombre',
  'Organization' => 'Organización',
  'Phone Number' => 'Número de teléfono',
  'Hello %name' => 'Hola %name',
);
```

Na sua utilização seria algo como:

```
//www.site.com/index.php?l=es
<text id="org"><?= t('Organization') ?></text>
// output: Organización
```